# Yii - multiple departments

Tags: yii, models, relation

Brand new to Yii, not new to PHP though. In the tutorial that Larry Ullman provides for Yii, I set up an Employees MySQL table and a Department table. The Employee table has a column, departmentId, which relationally links to Department to fetch the Id and get the name for that Department.

But here is my issue. Employees at my company can float in multiple departments (such as Customer Service, and Technical Support). My current Yii setup appears to only be set to fetch a single department. How could I make it so that I could enter multiple department IDs for an employee (separated by commas or anything such as `|`) and when Yii pulls down that employee, it will break those out and list all the departments for that employee?

I know this is bordering on the line of being too general, so I have posted some of my code below which contains the relations for Employee in the model:

```
    public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'department' => array(self::Belongs_To, 'Department', 'departmentId'),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need an n:m relationship: So one employee can be assigned to many departments and a department has many employees.
What you need is a so called pivot table to connect an employee to one or more departments like this:

tbl_employee (id, name, age, etc.)
tbl_employee_department (employee_id, department_id)
tbl_department (id, name, etc.)

Now your employee relation would look like this:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'departments' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Department', 'tbl_employee_department(employee_id, department_id)'),
    );
}
```

And your department relation would look like this:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'employees' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Employee', 'tbl_employee_department(employee_id, department_id)'),
    );
}
```

Now $employee->departments would return an array of department models. But what you want for forms is an arrayof department ids, so you have to do this in your employee model

```
public $departmentIds=array();

public function afterFind()
{
    if(!empty($this->departments)) {
        foreach($this->departments as $id=>$department)
            $this->departmentIds[]=$department->id;
    }
    parent::afterFind();
}

public function afterSave()
{
    $tx = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
    try {
        //delete all connections from this employee to any department first
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
        $command->delete('tbl_employee_department', 'employee_id=:id', array(':id'=>$this->id));
        //now reconnect the employee to the departments in the departmentIds array
        foreach($this->departmentsIds as $id) {
            $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
            $command->insert('tbl_employee_department', array(
                'employee_id' => $this->id,
                'department_id'=> (int)$id
            ));
        } 
        $tx->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $tx->rollback();
        throw new CException('Something bad happend. Cancelled transaction and rolled back data! '.$e->getMessage());
    }

    parent::afterSave();
}
```

This code fetches the departments from the database and stores their ids in the $departmentIds array as soon as you fetch an employee model from the database (via Employee::model()->find() etc.). The afterSave method gets called when you call $employee->save() and the saving process was successful. It will then start a transaction deleting all connections between this employee and all departments he is assigned to and then add all departments that are stored in the departmentIds array.

If you want to set this field via $model->setAttributes() you will have to declare it as safe (so Yii allows it to be mass assigned) by putting this in your employee rules

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
      //...all the other rules...
      array('departmentIds', 'safe'),
    );
```

}

I know, looks pretty complicated but it should give you an idea I guess. The only problem left is to set the ids of the departmentIds array via a form but you could explode a string of a texfield to do that etc. This shouldn't be that hard I guess

Comment: I tried the above changes. i modified the pivot table name to be EmployeeDepts. I am getting the error: **'departments.EmployeeDepts(employeeId' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT \`departments\`.\`id\` AS \`t1_c0\`, \`departments\`.\`name\` AS \`t1_c1\` FROM \`Department\` \`departments\` WHERE (\`departments\`.\`EmployeeDepts(employeeId\`=:ypl0) AND (\`departments\`.\`departmentId)\`=:ypl1)**

Comment: My relation looks like this: `'departments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Department', 'EmployeeDepts(employeeId, departmentId)')`

Comment: so it looks like it is not recognizing the table as a different table, but instead using the Department table... how do I get it to point to the correct table?

Comment: okay, so changing from HAS_MANY to MANY_MANY cleared the error, but when I view the employee record through the site, it still just lists the departmentId that is in the Employee table instead of listing all the departmentIds that are in the EmployeeDepts for that employeeId

Comment: 1.) Sorry, of course it is MANY_MANY, my fault. 2.) There should not be any departmentId in your employee table. You don't need that if you have a many_many relationship with a pivot table. 3.) You'll have to change your form view to show your departmentIds array. You could fill a textField with "implode(',', $model->departsmentIds)". Just remember to "explode" that string back to the departmentIds array before saving the model

Comment: got it.. thanks. I figured an implode but didnt know if there was a Yii function for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the 'Belongs To' relationship type, you will have to use the 'Many Many' relationship for your models. More on model relationships [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr).

'Many Many' relationships require you to add another table to store these relationships in, something like this:

Employees_Departments: id | employee_id | department_id

You can then remove the department_id column from the employee table.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the help. That was what I was thinking and have started doing. Im following some of the advice from @haensel above if you see anything that could use improvement on my new problem now. Thanks again!